# Violin plots appear as vertical lines

Tags: seurat, ggplot2

I want to perform a violin plot from a Seurat object and I rather have vertical lines. How can I stop this and rather have a standard Violin plot?

code

```
Seurat::VlnPlot(object, features=c("LTA", "LTB"), group.by = "group",
    pt.size = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Why have you set the point size to zero? I expect that would stop the points from displaying on the plot.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason is simply LTA and LTB not being expressed (or their expression not being detected due to technical limitations). If you would set the `pt.size` argument to something else than 0, you would see a big blob of dots at point 0.0 (depending on the number of cells/data points).